# Создать структуру HTML из JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
function renderWorked(itemsi) {            
    $('#cases').append('<div class="works block" >   </div>'); // создаём див, в который будет добавляться информация с джсон      
    var containered = $('.block'), html = [], i, item;  // сюда должно добавлять 
    for (i = 0; i < itemsi.length; i ++) {
        item = itemsi[i];
        if ($("div")) { //если этот код убрать, то все загребет под одну категорию
            //-----собирает html добавляя данные с json  
            html.push('<div  class="works' + item['Category']  + '"' + 'style="float: left"'+ 'hide">'); //вставляет div с нужной категорией
            html.push('<div class="work-wrapper closed w' + item['Wraper']+'">');
            html.push('<img data-video="' + item['data-video'] + '" src="/Kvinto/img/works/preview/' + item['image-data']  +   'data-alt-src="' + item['data-alt-src'] + '.jpg title="" alt=""   >');
            html.push('<h3>'+ item['title'] + '</h3>');
            html.push('</div>');
        }     
        html.push('</div>');
        containered.html(html.join(''));
        // html.push('<div class="clearfix"></div>');
    }
}

var workItemsed = [  //json файл
    // kategori_1
    {'Wraper': '1','Category': 'Digital','data-video': '5n_aW-dPRIQ0', 'data-alt-src':'5n_aW-dPRIQ0', 'image-data': '5n_aW-PdRIQ0.jpg"', 'title': 'Digital <br>  (пример1)' },
    // kategori_2
    {'Wraper': '2','Category': 'iron75','data-video': 'r3-K4vdvRe6E', 'data-alt-src':'r3-K4dvvRe6E', 'image-data': 'r3-K4vvdRe6E.jpg"', 'title': 'Digital <br> rill)' }]

renderWorked(workItemsed);
```

Получается такая разметка:

```
<div class="Digital" style="float: left" hide"=""> </div>
<div class="Digital" style="float: left" hide"=""> </div>
```

А нужно, чтобы получилась такая:

```
<div class="Digital" "=""> 
    <div class="work-wrapper">  
        <img/>
    </div> 
</div>
```

То есть `div` категория, и в эту категорию всё помещается согласно JSON структуре.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создавать элементы следующим способом

```
var main_div = $( "<div/>", { class : "Digital" } ).appendTo( *родительский элемент* );
var div = $( "<div/>", { class : "work-wrapper" } ).appendTo( main_div );
var img = $( "<img/>" ).appendTo( div );
```

`<div class="Digital" "="">`   - вот это какая то ерунда. Чего вы хотели этим добиться?